replacing the preposition “til” with “to”
I am trying to find out if it's acceptable in the English language to replace the preposition til with the preposition to.
For example, can I say "there are 20 days to Christmas" instead of "there are 20 days til Christmas"?

In that case, yes. Arbitrarily, no.

I would write it as till or until or perhaps 'til.

@Henry - yes. til is an error.

Maybe, but it would sound very awkward.
till is an abbreviation for until. So the best thing to say would be:

There are 20 days until Christmas.

Other ways to say the same thing:

There are 20 days left before Christmas.
Christmas is in 20 days.

From Dictionary.com:
Till and until mean the same thing. Till is the correct spelling of the truncated preposition until. Till is actually older than unti. 'Til, with one L, is an informal and poetic shortening of until. The form 'till, with an additional L, is rarely if ever used today. Til and its apostrophe-laden cousins ‘til and ‘till are considered incorrect.

What you've written is not in fact true: till is ɴᴏᴛ an abbreviation for until, just as to is not an abbreviation for unto. Please see Wiktionary about this widespread misunderstanding, especially what it says about it in its Etymology and Usage Notes sections.

I provided some additional information above. I never said anything about "unto."

You still should not say that till is an abbreviation for until. It is not, and never has been.

Merriam-Webster gives as a meaning of "to" "until", examples "from eight to five", "up to now". It's fine to use "to" in this way.
